# Difference between typedef and C++11 type alias

Tags: c++11

I'm reading template aliases here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias

And I'm wondering, even if it's written on the very first line of the page I linked, what's the difference between a typedef and a type alias (`using mytype = T;`)

Aren't they interchangeable?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**There is absolutely no difference between both.**

If you take a look at the standard :

> **7.1.3 The typedef speciﬁer [dcl.typedef ]**
>
> A *typedef-name* can also be introduced by an *alias-declaration*. The *identifier* following the `using` keyword becomes a *typedef-name*. **It has the same semantics as if it were introduced by the `typedef` specifier.** In particular, it does not define a new type and it shall not appear in the *type-id*.
>
> **7.3.3 The using declaration [namespace.udecl]**
>
> If a *using-declaration* uses the keyword *typename* and specifies a dependent name (14.6.2), the name introduced by the *using-declaration* is treated as a *typedef-name*.

---

However from this page : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias

It is said :

> Type aliases are similar to [typedefs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef), **however, have the advantage of working with templates.**

It seems that this

```
// template type alias
template<class T> using ptr = T*;
// the name 'ptr<T>' is now an alias for pointer to T
ptr<int> x;
```

is only possible with the `using` directive.

---

And do not forget that this is a C++11 feature. Some compilers do not support it yet.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference.

**typedef gives an alias name for the type.**